# Как можно минимизированный CSS привести в нормальный вид?

Tags: css

Как можно минимизированный CSS привести в нормальный вид программными средствами?

Подходит:

- Библиотека
- Программный код
- API сервиса

Не подходит:

- Онлайн-сервис (этот вариант привлекает спам)

Comment: [Online CSS Unminifier](http://mrcoles.com/blog/css-unminify/) Такое попробуйте.

Comment: То что вы ищете, называется `pretty print` - аглогитмов много можно найти, в том числе рабочих страничек opensource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В PHPStorm можно минифицированный код привести в нормальный (**Code** > **Reformat Code** - **Ctrl + Alt + L**). Комбинация может разниться от версии Схемы (то бишь настроек редактора). Указано сочетания для **Default Scheme**.

По поводу минификации кода есть отдельные статьи и плагины.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться программой KOALA. Не только минимизирует код, но компилирует LESS  и SASS в css  минимизирует js файлы и многое другое.

А на счет привести в нормальный вид пользуюсь плагином, html-css-js prettify

кнопки ctrl+shift+h выравнивает код js css и html